# Converting Ada code to C#

Tags: c#, translation, ada, checksum

So I need help converting this ada code int c#, it's basically a checksum algorithm.

*ADA:*

```
CHECKSUM_VALUE := ((ROTATE_LEFT_1_BIT(CHECKSUM_VALUE)) xor (CURRENT_VALUE));
```

This is what I could come up with:

*C#:*

```
checksum = RotateLeft(checksum, rotateCount, sizeof(ushort) * 8) ^ word;
```

RotateLeft Function:

```
    public static int RotateLeft(int value, ushort rotateCount, int dataSize)
    {
        return (value << rotateCount) | (value >> (dataSize - rotateCount));
    }
```

However when comparing the checksum results from the ada and C# algorithms, they do not match so I think my conversion isn't correct, anyone who has used ada before can give some input would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Is the value of rotateCount correct?(In this case it must be 1)

Comment: You have an `int value` (Int32) but you roate it by 16. provide all C# and Ada dataypes.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The shift function is based on this: xgc.com/manuals/m1750-ada/m1750/x2733.html

Comment: I see no problem with the `xor` -> `^` translation; your problem is most likely with the rotate-left function. Please show us the the spec and body of `ROTATE_LEFT_1_BIT`, and the types involved. If you can’t do that, show us what it does to data (for example, if you put in `16#52525252#` (Ada’s way of saying `0x52525252`) what comes out?)

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be with the C# and perhaps not with your interpretation of the ADA code. If you are truly rotating a 16 bit unsigned number as your post is implying, then you will need to mask the upper 2 bytes of the resulting integer value so that they do not contribute to the answer. Casting an uint x to ushort in C# will do the equivalent of x & 0x0000FFFF

```
    public static ushort RotateLeft(ushort value, int count)
    {
        int left = value << count;
        int right = value >> (16 - count);
        return (ushort)(left | right);
    }
```

Comment: The shift function is based on this: http://www.xgc.com/manuals/m1750-ada/m1750/x2733.html

Comment: bit 0 should be the most-significant bit

Comment: Yes, that's fine.  If you stick to unsigned types to avoid the problem that Simon mentioned above (shifting of the sign bit), and fix your RotateLeft function, then you should be getting the same answer.  The function in OP "public static int RotateLeft(int value, ushort rotateCount, int dataSize)" is NOT valid for all values of dataSize, and it probably wont do what you expect if you give it a negative number.  This is probably where your problem is.

Comment: I used your RotateLeft function but the results I get from the ADA algorithm still don't compare to the results i get with the C# algorithm, the translation looks ok to me so I don't know what else might be wrong.

Comment: I think you are going to need to post some more code then

Comment: Does the RotateLeft algorithm differ if the number scheme is LSB-0 or MSB-0? This one should MSB-0

Comment: So in C# (and other C languages) for an unsigned int x: x<<n == x*2^n and x>>n == x/2^n. I dont know anything about ADA, but what you seem to be suggesting is that in ADA it could be the opposite (x<<n == x/2^n and x>>n == x*2^n) If it is opposite, then you would just use a "RotateRight" function in your c# code, so give it a shot!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in C, since I don’t have a C# compiler.

You have `value` as an `int`, which is signed, so that a right shift extends the sign bit into the vacated space; so in `(value << rotateCount) | (value >> (dataSize - rotateCount))`, the right-hand half (`(value >> (dataSize - rotateCount))`) needs to have the top bits masked off. And I don’t know why you need `dataSize`, isn’t it `sizeof(value)`?

I think a better solution would be to use `unsigned`, so that a right shift introduces zeros into the vacated space.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned rotateLeft(unsigned value, int by) {
  const unsigned bits = sizeof(value) * 8;
  return (value << by) | (value >> (bits - by));
}

int main() {
  unsigned input = 0x52525252;
  unsigned result = input;
  printf("input:  %x\n", input);
  {
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      result = rotateLeft(result, 1);
      printf("result: %x\n", result);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
input:  52525252
result: a4a4a4a4
result: 49494949
result: 92929292
result: 25252525
result: 4a4a4a4a
result: 94949494
result: 29292929
result: 52525252
```